# Как использовать kbhit() и getch() в C++ на Linux

Tags: c++, библиотеки, ввод

я пишу небольшую "змейку" на С++ по [этому](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YRtq8yiG6DA) туториалу. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что мне нужно использовать `kbhit()` и `getch()` для считывания ввода пользователя. Данные возможности есть в библиотеке `conio.h`, которой на Linux нет. Также, я пробовал [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29335758/using-kbhit-and-getch-on-linux), но это не помогло, программа просто останавливалась и при вводе ничего не происходило.

Хотелось бы узнать, как реализовать такое на Linux, либо, есть ли какие-то альтернативы этой библиотеки?

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

bool GameOver;
const int height = 20;
const int width = 20;
int x, y, fruit_x, fruit_y, score;
enum eDirection { STOP, RIGHT, LEFT, UP, DOWN };
eDirection dir;

void setup() {
    GameOver = false;
    dir = STOP;
    x = width / 2 - 1;
    y = height / 2 - 1;
    fruit_x = rand() % width;
    fruit_y = rand() % height;
    score = 0;
}

void draw() {
    system("clear");

    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        cout << "#";
    }
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            if (j == 0 || j == width - 1)
        {
            cout << "#";
        }
        if (i == y && j == x)
        {
            cout << "0";
        }
        else if (i == fruit_y && j == fruit_x)
        {
            cout << "F";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << " ";
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        cout << "#";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void input() {
    if (_kbhit)
    {
        switch(getch())
    {
        case 'a':
            dir = LEFT;
            break;
        case 'd':
            dir = RIGHT;
            break;
        case 'w':
            dir = UP;
            break;
        case 's':
            dir = DOWN;
            break;
        case 'x':
            GameOver = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

void logic() {
    switch(dir)
    {
    case LEFT:
        x--;
        break;
    case RIGHT:
        x++;
        break;
    case UP:
        y--;
        break;
    case DOWN:
        y++;
        break;
    }
}


int main() {
    setup();
    while(!GameOver)
    {
        draw();
        input();
        logic();
    }

}
```

Comment: к сожалению простого способа читать в линуксе клавиатуру я не знаю, но вот нашлось такое: https://www.keithlantz.net/2011/10/a-keyboard-handler-and-timer-in-c-for-the-linux-platform/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получил ответ на англоязычном StackOverflow от пользователя [javad m](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64199477/12669503)

> Как сказал [zoelabbb](https://github.com/zoelabbb) сказал [здесь](https://github.com/zoelabbb/conio.h),
>
> Шаг 1 : Откройте терминал и произведите следующее:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update && upgrade
> sudo apt-get install git
> git clone https://github.com/zoelabbb/conio.h.git
> cd conio.h
> ```
>
> Шаг 2 :
>
> ```
> sudo cp conio.h /usr/include/
> ```
>
> **или** (шаг 2)
>
> В GUI, используя пакет `open-as-administrator`:
>
> ```
> Скопируйте file conio.h --> !! скопируйте файл, а не папку !!
> Перейдите в /usr/include/
> Нажмите правой кнопокой мыши по /usr/include/
> Выберите "Открыть от имени администратора"
> Вставьте файл conio.h
> ```
>
> **Наконец**, после **шагов 1 и 2**, вы можете использовать `#include <conio.h>` в вашем коде.